React-query refetchOnWindowFocus is not working in nextJs 12
i have reactjs app version

"react-query": "^3.39.2"
"next": "12.3.1",
"react": "^18.2.0"
I have setup code

  const queryClient = new QueryClient({
    defaultOptions: {
      queries: {
        refetchOnWindowFocus: false,
      },
    },
  })

      <QueryClientProvider client={queryClient}>
        {children}
      </QueryClientProvider>

And when i call api, i'm using this func
  const { data: campaignDetail, refetch: refetchCampaignDetail } = useQuery(
    ["getCampaignDetail", campaignId],
    async () => {
      if (campaignId) {
        const response = await getCampaignDetail(campaignId)
        setIsLoadingCampaign(false)
        return response?.data
      }
    },
    {
      refetchOnWindowFocus: "always",
      enabled: !!campaignId,
    },
  )

when i go to other tab on chrome and go back to my tab, it does nothing change. Any one can help me on this case?

in network tab do you see a call to api inside getCampaignDetail when you go back to the tab?

@VladVladov No Vlad, i don't see the call api when go back to the tab

but at first visit the data is loaded and the data comes from getCampaignDetail?

BTW the version you are using is outdated - its now @tanstack/react-query and is of v5

I know my version is outdated but i don't want to change newer version in this time. But if update is the only way to solve the problem, i will do it. Thanks my friend
